# how to use multiprocessing in python when a for loop applies function to each row

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Suppose I have a pandas dataframe containing input data, each row being one input set. Currently I'm looping over the rows and saving the results in an array. I'm wondering if this could be done / speed up via multiprocessing the for loop.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2],
                     [3, 4],
                     [5, 6]])

result = np.zeros((data.shape[0], 2))
for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    result[[i], :] = [np.mean(data.iloc[i,:]), np.max(data.iloc[i,:])]
```

How could the above be formulated using multiprocessing?

Answer (score 0):

```
import concurrent.futures

def do_something():
    # your logic code
  

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    # your_args that you passed to function
    your_args = []
    results = executor.map(do_something, your_args)
```